# Bald ist es soweit

Tags: translation, idiom

Could anyone tell me, how should I understand the expression in the title? As far as I can google, this is equivalent of "TAAADAM!", isn't it? Or at least it's my guessing.

Comment: I do not know what "TAADAM" means. The sentence in the title is not grammatically correct, by the way.

Comment: anyway, Tagesspiegel uses it. http://www.tagesspiegel.de/kultur/staatsoper-berlin-bald-ist-es-soweit/19904292.html

Comment: @Carsten: What? The word order is exactly the same. Anyway, what is incorrect (except for the missing exclamation point or full stop) about "Bald ist es soweit"?

Comment: @Carsten: just did. Got it.

Comment: Note regarding my comment above, which I will let stand because of its first part: The grammar in the title has been corrected.

Comment: A sentence (that short) without context is hard to interpret, especially if you want more precision than with a litteral translation such as *Soon it will be ready*. You should include some context. Where did you find that sentence?

Comment: Only a minor comment: I would have used "so weit" (instead of "soweit") - but admittedly, am not sure and would have to look it up (maybe it's one of these "Rechtschreibreform"-changes?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Es ist soweit* can be translated as *Time has come*, or *Now is the time*.

So *Bald ist es soweit* can be translated as *Soon, time will come*, or *Soon, it's the time* or, more loosely, *It won't take long anymore*.

*Bald is es soweit* => Es wird bald das passieren, worauf man gewartet hat, oder was man erwartet oder gehofft hat.

Comment: I like your precise translation into non-idiomatic (unambiguous) language *Es wird bald das passieren, worauf man gewartet hat*.

Comment: @Christian: thanks. You would say it to kids waiting for Santa, right? Or to people watching the ignition of the Olympic fire. I amended the line a little.

Comment: Yes, to kids about Santa, but there are many other use-cases, e.g. two people sitting in front of a computer and waiting for some operation to finalize; or people waiting for the green traffic light (altough then it would rather be *Gleich ist es soweit*, as *gleich* seems to be sooner than *bald*).

Comment: @Christian: indeed. *Bald* sounds a little weird for a traffic light.

Answer (score 2):

This saying is used to pronounce a soon coming happening.

Example:

> »Wann kommt die Ware denn endlich bei mir an?«  – »Bald ist es
>   soweit.«
>   *(»When do I get the goods finally?« – »Soon it will be done.«)*

Answer (score 0):

You could translate it with.
"It'll be here soon", it announces an event that is close to occuring.

if you want to stray a bit you could go towards "prepare for X"

Answer (score 0):

I would do it literally then go into more complex thinking. "Then it is shown" is how I would read it. As in be ready for something to come.

Comment: Hi, welcome to German SE. Could you clarify your answer a bit, maybe on the line of “Not long now” or “Coming very soon”? “Then it is shown” is not easily understandable ;)